# Django executes almost all .py files on every request

Tags: python, django, web

I have Django project with 6 apps. I added logging to every app's init.py, models.py and views.py files (outside any classes/functions) and I see that on every GET/POST request almost everyone of this files is executed.
Why is this happening and is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: Is it each GET/POST request or each time you change some file in your code?

Comment: I tried to load several pages by URL and on one of them sendBeacon POST request is sent, every time page loads or sendBeacon is sent in logs there are mark by almost all files from all apps , think I didtn't change any files during this..

Comment: Are you running on a development server or on production? I assume you might be running on heroku or some other service? Well they don't run your server _continuously_ and your server might be reloaded if the requests are not recent. And it is normal for all files to be loaded at the start because well we import all these files ourselves.

Comment: on virtual hosting.. did't know this, thanks for an answer

Comment: seems it makes loading much slower, or not? if it does is there any ways to make loading faster in this case (prevent some files execution maybe), or on virtual hosting you can't do anything with it?

Comment: it seems it's starting a new process for each request which causes modules to be re-imported again

Comment: can I do something with it or on virtual hosting this re-importing is unavoidable?